# Ubuntu 13.04: Find files ending in

Tags: linux, find

Can someone please tell me how I'm misusing find?

I want to find all files in a directory that end in .config.

```
$:~/esrc$ find . -type f
./t.config
./util/ebin/config.beam
./util/ebin/gen_spec.beam
./util/etc/util.config
./util/etc/v.config
./util/src/config.erl
./util/src/gen_spec.erl
./util/src/v.config
./util/u.config
```

My first thought was to use find . -type f -name *.config

Unfortunately that's only finding a file in the root directory.

```
$:~/esrc$ find . -type f -name *.config
./t.config
```

The same command does work to find all *.erl files though...

```
$:~/esrc$ find . -type f -name *.erl
./util/src/config.erl
./util/src/gen_spec.erl
```

Any clue why this works for *.erl but not *.config?

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the wild-card, i.e.

```
find . -type f -name '*.config'
```

Comment: That works thanks. Any clue why *.erl works but not *.config though?

Comment: It has to do about shell-expansion. The shell, e.g. bash expands the wildcard '*' before it is passed to the find command.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion here is that the wildcard (the * character) is interpreted by the *shell* **before** it makes it to the find command.  To get around that issue you need to escape it:

```
find . -type f -name \*.config
```

By escaping the * with the \ the shell will pass the * through to the find command.

An example would be if you had a file named `foo.config` in the current directory, the shell would expand the wildcard to foo.config and pass that to find, so the resulting command from the find command's perspective would be:

```
find . -type f -name foo.config
```